# Slice an image into segments, is there any android libraries to do this?

Tags: android, image

Does android have any built-in features to slice an image into portions? For example, if I have an image loaded in my application (such as setting on in an ImageView), is it possible to slice that image up into 4 equal segments and display each one separately?

If there is nothing out of the box, which libraries would enable me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You want to do that with a photo gave by the user at run-time?

Comment: Either, not to fussed where the image is coming from. It will either be loaded from the device(i.e., from the SD card), or they can take a photo "on the fly" with the camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with bitmaps, you can use [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to extract sub-images.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Any implications using Bitmaps and their sizes? Any issues with large bitmaps on mobile devices?

Comment: Well, they have less memory and processing power than desktop/server machines, potentially lower bandwidth (and expensive bandwidth)